# How to test json fast api rails with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have the following serialize:

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :name
end
```

I'm trying to test the name

```
require 'rails_helper'


describe 'UserSerializer' do
    it 'serializes json' do
        result =  UserSerializer.new({_id:"1ew345",name: 'kdlls'}).serialized_json
        expect(result.name).to be eq('kdlls')
    end
end
```

Error:
 FastJsonapi::MandatoryField:
       id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec

Comment: You should be able to provide any value for the id really. I would use FactoryBot to just generate a stubbed record and do `expect(result.name).to be eq(model.name)`.

Comment: Same mistake with id

Comment: Could you make an example with factory?

Comment: `let(:user) { FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:user) }; let(:json) { UserSerializer.new(user).serialized_json }; let(:attributes){ json['data']['attributes'] }` ... `expect(attributes['name']).to eq user.name`.

Comment: I tried, I can not test with factory bot

Comment: It probably expects object not hash. Try passing `double(id: '1ew345', name: 'kdlls')` instead of a hash if you cannot use FactoryBot